# Divergence to $\infty$ basic questions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

i was given this exercises:

1) Show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k(k+1)} = 1$$
2) Show that $\exists L\in\Bbb R   $ such that
 $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2} = L$$
3)Show that $\nexists L\in\Bbb R   $ such that
 $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt k} = L$$
 The Restrictions that it need to be solved with any Knowledge on Cauchy criterion and sires,just basic limit properties.

The idea is to prove that they are non decreasing sequences so if they bounded they have limit and otherwise they diverges.

My problem was with Q(2) and Q(3),in Q(1) i can decompose it and its a telescopic sum (i thought maybe i need to use it for 2 and 3) ,i just cant figure how to bound (2)(without to imply that the harmonic sires converges :/ so that can't be the right way) or to disprove that it boundless same go to 3.

I hope someone can show me how should i go for (2) so i can go on to (3)

Comment: For Q2., note that it is simply $\zeta(2)=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: Use the integral test! If $f(x)$ is positive, decreasing, and continuous, and $f(n) = a_n$, then the series $a_n$ converges iff $\int_1^{\infty} f(x)dx$ converges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your questions have already been answered many times on MSE. Anyway,
$$\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+1}$$
leads to:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1-\frac{1}{N+1}$$
so that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}=1.$$
Then you can use the Mengoli series to prove that $\zeta(2)$ is finite, since:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}\leq 1+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{n(n+1)}\leq 2$$
and at last you may use:
$$ \sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}}$$
to prove that:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=1+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}\geq 2\sqrt{N}-1. $$

Answer (score 2):

- For the question $2$ , use the firt question $\frac{1}{n^2}\leq \frac{1}{n(n-1)}$
- For the third question $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}=\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt k}$

Comment: How is $\dfrac{1}{n^2}\leq \dfrac{1}{n(n+1)}$ ?

Comment: It's a mistake, I corrected it, and this just a hint you have to exclude for example $n=1$ and $\cdots$